# Can I use bonsai liquid fertilizer on my regular houseplants?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, fertilizer, bonsai

I have 0.5 liter bonsai liquid fertilizer that has outlived my bonsai. I have tried to give it away for free in my local Facebook plant groups, but as it seems no one is really into *bonsai* in my area. So I was wondering if I could use them on my regular houseplants.

These are the ingredients (NPK 3,8,5?):

- N (3.0 m/v%)
- P<sub>2</sub>O<sub>5</sub> (7.8 m/v%)
- K<sub>2</sub>O (5.1 m/v%)
- Cu (0.002 m/v%)
- Fe (0.02 m/v%)
- Mn (0.01 m/v%)
- Zn (0.002 m/v%)

These are the type of plants that I have:

- *Pothos*
- *Chinese evergreens*
- *Dracena*
- *Monstera*
- *Philodendron hederaceum* (regular green and *Brasil*), *Rojo congo* and a *Golden dragon*.

Apart from these I have a *ZZ plant*, a *Yucca*, a *Pandanus* and an *Aloe vera*.

Which plants and how often could I fertilize during a growing season without worrying of over fertilizing or other problems?

My *Pothos* are still growing could I use the fertilizer on them during the winter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation of your bonsai fertiliser isn't much use to the type of plants you mention; they will require higher levels of nitrogen. For instance, Baby Bio is a good liquid houseplant fertiliser, and its NPK is roughly 10-4-7, so you can easily see the difference in the NPK value between that and your bonsai fertiliser. Whatever you decide to do with the fertiliser you have, I'm afraid I would not recommend it for your other houseplants.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know maybe a way to dispose it safely?

Comment: @BenceKaulics The NPK ratio is be about right for tomato fertilizer. Try advertising it as that on your Facebook groups.